# Xpath selenium Webdriver to automate sales force

Tags: java, selenium

after sales force sprint change not able to get lightning-formatted-text using .gettext

i tried with `.getAttribute("innerhtml")` and `.getAttribute("textContent")`

```
workOrderDescriptionEnglish = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(
                                "//span[text()='Description (English)']//following::lightning-formatted-text[1])[1]")))
                                .getAttribute("textContent");
```

not fetching anything and no errors

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Also you didn't provide html sample.

Answer (score 1):

you can give try to getText() method on the element found.

Moreover, you can try this with parent element(s) and do some parsing in case of specific validations to be made against text displayed.

Comment: the very first time i tried with getText() method it is not working..